# compare and delete json data using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Below is my json code:

```
{
    "uID": "4564646",
    "favorites": [

        {   "name" : "my store",
            "id" : "87654321",
            "items": 
            [
                { 
                    "productID": "46565",
                    "title": "Project",
                    "type": "Weekend Project"
                },

                { 
                    "productID": "112",
                    "title": "Bathroom",
                    "type": "Weekend Project"
                },


                { 
                    "productID": "785",
                    "title": "link",
                    "type": "main Project"
                }

            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

Now i want to check the PRODUCTID for each and delete the entry from  items which matches my product id 112 .
I want to use javascript only, the array items is not fixed and also  Do i have to parse the json before applying the deletion method.

Comment: What have you tried? You should just be able to loop over the items and use `delete item;` if the `productID` is `112`

Comment: Yes, you have to parse your JSON string even before checking the `productID`.

Comment: @danny: But danny can u explain with code how to compare and delete.

Comment: @Danny No, `delete` should probably not be used. It sets that array element to `undefined`, instead of removing the element.

Comment: @Barmar correct, I did not know `delete` would do that for the array. `splice` would be what he wants.

Comment: why my question is been voted down, can anyone explain. Im new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json_string);
var fav_items = obj.favorites[0].items;
for (var i = fav_items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (fav_items[i].productID == 112) {
        fav_items.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Note that you need to do the loop backwards, because when you splice out an element from the array, all the elements after it get there indexes shifted down. If you do a normal upward loop, you'll skip over the elements after the ones you delete.

Comment: Can't you simplify the loop parameters to `(var i=fav_items.length; i>0; i--)` ?

Comment: No, because the first iteration will try to access `fav_items[i]`, and that will be outside the array if `i = fav_items.length`.

Comment: /me smacks head. Ignore me!

Comment: I'm always intimidated by you, because like, you're so pro and your answers are always really good. I have a lot to learn from you <3

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.favorites[0].items.length; i++) {
    if (data.favorites[0].items[i].productID != 112) {
        data.favorites[0].items.splice(i, 1); 
        i--; //DONT FORGET THIS
    }
}
```

`splice` can remove array elements - dont forget the `i--` though when splicing in a loop as the array has the potential to shorten with each iteration.

Comment: An alternative way is iterating backwards. Then you can forget about `i--`.